# What is the difference between subsite and document library?

Tags: sharepoint, document

I created a subsite and document lirabry, they both seem to work the same and I can't tell the difference between them. Please advise.

Answer (score 1):

A subsite is a site which contains libraries, lists and other settings.

A document library is a location on a site where you can upload, create, update, and collaborate on files with team members.

Comment: I want to upload documents, I can upload it on the subsite and also on a document library. What is the difference? Both are pages with different link. Which should I use? Please advise.

Comment: " I can upload it on the subsite" , the location that you uploaded document on the susbite should be a library of a subsite. In SharePoint, just libraries could be used to stored documents. You can find libraries at the site collection level and subsite level. Hope my reply is clear.

Answer (score 0):

A document library contains documents i.e. Microsoft Word files.
A subsite is basically a SharePoint website. A subsite can contain many things that a document library can't.

Comment: What do you meant by a website? Document library has it's own url, just like a subsite.

Comment: @momtp369 I'm not trying to be mean but I think SharePoint might be a bit too advanced for you. Get some formal training if you can, I assume you're asking this for work related reasons so they should prepare you

Answer (score 0):

The only noticeable difference is ability to update sub site permissions when there are more then 100,000 documents. Libraries, lists and folders don't support permission changes after the limit.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office365/servicedescriptions/sharepoint-online-service-description/sharepoint-online-limits